# how to show two replies, and fold the rest of them under view replies. (I'm having hard time showing two replies)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a commenting system and it currently folds all replies. I want to show two replies and then fold all of them. now I looked into this http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Frpmj/3/ but I'm not quite getting it because I use for-loop for the replies. Here's my code.

```
<div class="replyInfo">
    {% if not comment.is_child %}
        <div class="wholeReply">
          {% if comment.comment_count %}
        <a href='#' class='replies'>           
         {{comment.comment_count}}</a>
          {% endif %}
        <div class="got_replies">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        {% for child in comment.get_children %}
        <li>
      {{ child.get_comment }}
        </li><hr>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
$('.replies').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".got_replies").fadeToggle(); 
})
$(".got_replies").fadeToggle(); 

</script>
```

can someone please help me out?

Comment: Is this using Twig? If so, can you tag your question with that?

Comment: @trincot Can you post your rendered html?

Comment: @LarryLane, did you think I was the OP?

Comment: Yeah i type in the wrong name, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice()` function to select the first two elements with a class name of `reply`.  You will have to add the class name `reply` to your html of course. [Live Preview](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/GZNvQd)

**HTML with added class name:**

```
<div class="replyInfo">
    {% if not comment.is_child %}
        <div class="wholeReply">
          {% if comment.comment_count %}
        <a href='#' class='replies'>           
         {{comment.comment_count}}</a>
          {% endif %}
        <div class="got_replies">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        {% for child in comment.get_children %}
        <li class="reply"><!--added class to your li element-->
      {{ child.get_comment }}
        </li><hr>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    $('.replies').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".got_replies").find(".reply").slice(0,2).fadeToggle(); 
});

$(".reply").fadeToggle();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Larry, but I want the comments(not the first two) to be folded untill I click view all comments link. I put $(".got_replies").fadeToggle(); 
at the end but then the whole js doesn't work, can you give me some tip?

Comment: @emfour I will gladly help but please clarify. I thought you wanted to hide every comment after the second comment until the user clicks on the button?

Comment: what I'm trying to do, currently every comment is shown and when I click the button only the first two comments show up

Comment: So you want only the first two to show when the button is clicked?

Comment: yes sir and are you good at ajax? I'm having this problem and it's driving me nuts do you mind taking a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015299/form-submission-nicely-without-refreshing-page-with-ajax-i-can-get-it-to-succes

Comment: I could help you with that, lets get the first problem solved and then we can move on to that one.

Comment: @emfour I will be away from my desk for about an hour but I will hop back on and fix my solution to match your requirements when I get back.

Comment: @emfour Ok try the live preview now, It should start with no replies shown and then show the first two if you if click on the button. Hopefully this is close to what you are trying to do, if not just let me know.

Comment: @emfour if it works for you I will edit the explanation to match the solution.

Comment: @emfour Not a probem I am a glad i could help.

Comment: ^^ you are awesome, do you mind giving me some hand for the ajax problem I've been having since yesterday, I saw you left a comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015299/form-submission-nicely-without-refreshing-page-with-ajax-i-can-get-it-to-succes

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are hiding the whole div.
I didn't test it, but try this:

```
<script>
$('.replies').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".got_replies").children("ul").children("li:nth-child(n+2)").fadeToggle(); 
})

</script>
```

Comment: Your code works but it is worth noting that the nth-child selector doesn't use a zero based index like JavaScript arrays so if you want to toggle everything after the 2nd li then you will have to use n + 3.

Comment: No problem It is an easy fix