# form submission nicely without refreshing page with ajax; I can get it to success alert but lost at the next step(form going through)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to use ajax for my commenting system. right now commenting works fine except everytime I submit the page gets refreshed. So I studied ajax, and tried implementing it. 
I have two forms, comment and reply

```
<form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}' class='commentForAjax'>{% csrf_token %}
<input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='{{ post.id }}'/>
<input type='hidden' name='origin_path' value='{{ request.get_full_path }}'/>

{% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}
</form>

    <div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='post_id' id='post_id' value='{% url "comment_create" %}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='origin_path' id='origin_path' value='{{ comment.get_origin }}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}

        </form>
        </div>


<script>
 $(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/comment/create/',
    data:{
      post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
      origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(),
      parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(){
      alert('it worked');
    }
  })

 })
</script>
```

every time I submit comment I get it worked, but form is not going through I don't know what to do, without script commenting works so I need to connect it some how but don't know how. Also I don't get any errors. 
as for my python code

```
#Comments
urlpatterns += patterns('comments.views',
    url(r'^comment/create/$', 'comment_create_view', name='comment_create'),
)

comment views.py
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = None

        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                #affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()
                #print "this is"
                affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()

                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(origin_path)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

I don't know what to put in my success function I did

```
 success: function(html, textStatus) {
                 $('.commentForAjax').replaceWith(html);
                 bindPostCommentHandler();
            },
```

but this won't work

Comment: Do you know how to use the inspection panel in your browser? Hopefully you are using chrome or firefox to debug your app. You can right click on the page and then click inspect element from the menu. A panel should appear that will say console,html,net,etc. Click on the console tab and then submit your form and see if a http request appears.  If it does you can expand it and then click on the html tab which should show you what is loaded in the page and if your server script has thrown any errors?  Let me know what you find out and I can help you out further.

Comment: @LarryLane yeah I inspected element but there's no error, it's just I don't know what to put in my success function. I'll edit what I tried

Comment: Ok I posted a solution that should hopefully get you going in the right direction. Give the steps a try and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are trying to do is submit the following form with a class name of `commentForAjax`.

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}' class='commentForAjax'>{% csrf_token %}
<input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='{{ post.id }}'/>
<input type='hidden' name='origin_path' value='{{ request.get_full_path }}'/>

{% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}
</form>
```

Based on your previous comments the on submit function is firing because I believe you said the alert function was being called in your success function. With that being said there are a couple of things I believe you should try.

**Step 1.**

Inside of your ajax function replace the data property value with `$(this).serialize()` that way you can make sure all of your data makes to your server script intact since you are using post variables to retrieve your data. Right now you are sending a JavaScript object to your server script as data.  I do not know how Python works so I couldn't tell you how to parse it on the server side but if you were going to send it in that fashion you would have to `JSON.stringify()` it first so you could parse it as JSON. You also have to specifiy your dataType as json(`dataType:'json'`).

```
$(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/comment/create/',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(){
          alert('it worked');
        }
      });
```

**Step 2.**

The previous step should have fixed your data problem but now you have to get the data in your success call back function.

```
$(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/comment/create/',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data){
          alert(data);//<--- alert data returned from server
        }
      });
```

Now your server script must print something to the screen in order for it to be returned inside of the data variable otherwise nothing will be alerted.

**Review:**

1. Make sure your path is correct in the url property and the Ajax call is successful.
2. Serialize the data sent over http Post.
3. Make sure the Python script is printing or outputting something to the page  or screen.
4. Use the data variable passed in the call back to do something with it like alert it or append it to an element using JQuery.